# Run a main java application outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maven, executable-jar

I have a maven java project on eclipse, it runs fine. I am trying to run it as an application outside eclipse (as an executable jar). I have tried to export it as jar file and run it, but it is not working. How can I export a maven project from eclipse and run it as an executable application outside eclipse???

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: when a double click on the jar. It is not runnning

Comment: That may be a problem of double-click. Did you try running with `java -jar myjar.jar`? At least you'll see an error message, so you'll know why it is not working, e.g. you're missing the `Main-Class` declaration in the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: I have exported it again and it is running.But when I jar it, it is not jarring the 'src/main/resources' which contains the images and stuff. Also, I have log files that are not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Create jar file using maven packaging.

```
$ mvn package
```

You can refer this step by step [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/).

Once the jar is ready, run it by using below command.

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

**Important:**

If you dont have a manifest in your jar invoking java -jar will not work.

Use this command if you dont have a manifest:

```
java -cp <jar-file-name>.jar full.package.name.ClassName
```

Comment: "You can refer this step by step tutorial.", "If you dont have a manifest in your jar invoking java -jar will not work." -- please don't provide links as they get outdated: include the relevant portion in your answer. As you mention, it doesn't work if there is no manifest to indicate which class to run, so I believe that's the part that you need to include in your answer.

Comment: @Erwin, Thanks for guiding... :-)